# jQuery get current element (x)html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the next input element:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="user name" 
    helper="formText" defvalue="user name" class="filling" />
```

How can I get this html by id `"username"` with help of jQuery?

I try to make it with `get()`, `html()`. But I want to get html of current element.

Thank you in advance.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: So you want the HTML of the input tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get the *exact* HTML (as different browsers handle this differently), but closest you can get is appending a cloned version to a temporary element and taking the `.innerHTML` of that, like this:

```
var html = $("<div/>").append($("#username").clone()).html();
```

Comment: JQuery docs say `html` doesn't work on xhtml documents? Oh, no it says 'xml documents'...does that include xhtml?

Comment: @sje397 - nope, that's a different topic/handling :)